# use beautifulsoup to parse a specific word from a tag in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, tags

i use beautifulsoup to parsing xml file so the parsing done by tag name
but can i put another word for searching inside the tag?

```
  Data = soup.find_all('Data')
for Data in Data:
    Data = Data.get_text()
```

Data is name of the tag but can i select a word inside this tag to parsing it maybe like this

```
Data = soup.find_all("Data", name = '"ObjectClass')
```

for Data in Data:
Data = Data.get_text()
print (Data)

i tried this but get this error
TypeError: Tag.find_all() got multiple values for argument 'name'

This is an XML example:

```xml
<Document>
  <Data Name="ObjectClass">computer</Data>
  <Data Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName">ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime</Data>
  <Data Name="ObjectClass">computer</Data>
  <Data Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName">ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime</Data>
</Document>
```

So I want to search on only name =object class

Comment: Provide sample XML and desired output.  Not clear what you want.

Comment: @MarkTolonen this is xml example <Data Name="ObjectClass">computer</Data><Data Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName">ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime</Data> <Data Name="ObjectClass">computer</Data><Data Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName">ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime</Data>                          so i want to search in only object class but its in the same tag

Comment: Please edit the question to provide and format the new information. I don’t know what “only object class but I its in the same tag” means. What result do you want?

Comment: @MarkTolonen this result only Name="ObjectClass">computer

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72748906/edit) the question! Also that isn't a proper XML.

Comment: @MarkTolonen done and i tried to do this but i got an error                                           Data = soup.find_all("Data", name = '"ObjectClass')
for Data in Data:
    Data = Data.get_text()
    print (Data)

Comment: `for Data in Data:` won't work.  Need different variables names for the iteration to work.  Please put *all information* in the question, format it properly, and if you have an error post that text as well.  Make sure to **run** the code you post and that it reproduces the problem.  See [ask] and [mcve] for site requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This will get only `Data` tags with `Name="ObjectClass"`.  It requires `pip install bs4 lxml` for external libraries:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '''\
<Document>
  <Data Name="ObjectClass">computer</Data>
  <Data Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName">ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime</Data>
  <Data Name="ObjectClass">computer</Data>
  <Data Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName">ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime</Data>
  <Other Name="ObjectClass">other</Other>
</Document>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,'xml')
for data in soup.find_all('Data',Name='ObjectClass'):
    print(data.get_text())
```

Output:

```
computer
computer
```

Note that case matters (`Name` not `name`).

Answer (score 0):

One liner without any external library :-)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''\
<Document>
  <Data Name="ObjectClass">computer1</Data>
  <Data Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName">ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime</Data>
  <Data Name="ObjectClass">compute2r</Data>
  <Data Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName">ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime</Data>
  <Other Name="ObjectClass">other</Other>
</Document>
'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
object_class_data = [x.text for x in root.findall('.//Data[@Name="ObjectClass"]')]
print(object_class_data)
```

output

```
['computer1', 'compute2r']
```